# Cut common strings from multiple files and paste them into another file

Tags: ruby, powershell

So lets say I have 5 files: f1, f2, f3, f4, f5. How can I remove the common strings (same text in all files) from all 5 files and put them into a 6th file, f6? Please let me know.

**Format of the files:**

```
property.a.p1=some string
property.b.p2=some string2
          .
          .
          .
property.zzz.p4=123455
```

So if the above is an excerpt from file 1 and files 2 to 5 also have the string *`property.a.p1=some string`* in them, then I'd like to remove that string from files 1 to 5 and put it in file 6. Each line of each file is on a new line. Thus, I would be comparing each string on a newline one by one. Each file is around 400 to 600 lines.

I found this on a forum for removing common strings from two files using ruby:
`$ ruby -ne 'BEGIN {a=File.read("file1").split(/\n+/)}; print $_ if a.include?($_.chomp)' file2`

Comment: As in, if file 1, file 2, file 3, file 4 and file 5 all contain the string 'hello world' then it should be removed from all 5 files and appended to the 6th file.

Comment: Is this on a line-by-line / word-by-word basis or are you literally trying to consider every possible substring of each file?

Comment: that's still vague. Do you want to compare word by word, line by line, or character by character? What about one file with `hello world` and one with `world hello`? What about `hello world` and `hell o world`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this does what you want.  It's a "2-pass" solution, the first pass uses a hash table to find the common lines, and the second uses that to filter out any lines that match the commons.

```
$files = gci "file1.txt","file2.txt","file3.txt","file4.txt","file5.txt"

$hash = @{}
$common = new-object system.collections.arraylist

foreach ($file in $files) {
 get-content $file | foreach {
 $hash[$_] ++
 }
}

$hash.keys |% {
 if ($hash[$_] -eq 5){[void]$common.add($_)}
}


$common | out-file common.txt

[regex]$common_regex = ‘^(‘ + (($common |foreach {[regex]::escape($_)}) –join “|”) + ‘)$’

foreach ($file in $files) {
 $new_file = get-content $file |? {$_ -notmatch $common_regex}
 $new_file | out-file "new_$($file.name)"
}
```

Comment: gci is the powershell alias for get-childitem.

Comment: I ended up writing the solution in Java. This works I think but wish to enforce more restrictions while comparing the strings and what not. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Create a table in an SQL database like this:

```
create table properties (
    file_name  varchar(100) not null,  -- Or whatever sizes make sense
    prop_name  varchar(100) not null,
    prop_value varchar(100) not null
)
```

Then parse your files with some simple regular expressions or even just [`split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001165):

```
prop_name, prop_value = line.strip.split('=')
```

dump the parsed data into your table, and do a bit of SQL to find the properties that are common to all files:

```
select prop_name, prop_value
from properties
group by prop_name, prop_value
having count(*) = $n
```

Where `$n` is replaced by the number of input files. Now you have a list of all the common properties and their values so write those to your new file, remove them from your `properties` table, and then spin through all the rows that are left in `properties` and write them to the appropriate files (i.e. the file named by the `file_name` column).

You say that the files are "huge" so you probably don't want to slurp all of them into memory at the same time. You could do multiple passes and use a hash-on-disk library for keeping track of what has been seen and where but that would be a waste of time if you have an SQL database around and everyone should have, at least, SQLite kicking around. Managing large amounts of structured data is what SQL and databases are for.